# Azure VM and AD Setup

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Kindly let me know

Setup the Virtual machine - configure DHS, TCP/IP, Firewall setting

Map to Virtual Network and Subnet

create a vm in other region and set up the Activie directly to setup accces the vm based on user group

Access both VM and files in the vms based on  AD Settings Configure Apps based on AD Settings

Comment: Is there a question somewhere here? Is it a programming question (others are off-topic)?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the question is too broad and unclear to answer it better. Also, you have not update your specific question. I suppose you want to create a Windows server VM and then join this Azure VM to a managed domain.

If so, you can follow these step1-step3 from this doc: [Join a Windows Server virtual machine to a managed domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm-portal). It shows how to create Azure VM and how to join the virtual machine to an Azure Active Directory Domain Services (Azure AD DS) managed domain.

Also, you may want to know these information below:

[Azure Active Directory (AD) Domain Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview)

[What is Azure Active Directory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis)